# Question in tensor calculation

Tags: solution-verification, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, tensors

I need to prove $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ it's a antisymmetric:
$$\omega_{\mu\nu}=-\omega_{\nu\mu}$$
according to these property:
\begin{align*}g_{\rho\sigma} = g_{\mu\nu}\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \ \rho} \Lambda^\nu_{\ \ \ \sigma} \end{align*}

$$\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu}=\delta^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu} + \omega^\mu_{{\ \ \ \nu}}$$
then:

$$(\delta_{\rho}^{\mu}+\omega_{\rho}^{\mu})g_{\mu\nu}(\delta_{\sigma}^{\nu}+\omega_{\sigma}^{\nu})+o(\omega^{2})=g_{\rho\sigma}$$

We get this:

$$\tag{*}g_{\rho\sigma}+\omega_{\rho}^{\mu}g_{\mu\nu}\delta_{\sigma}^{\nu}+\omega_{\sigma}^{\nu}g_{\mu\nu}\delta_{\rho}^{\mu}+o(\omega^2)=g_{\rho\sigma}$$
Finally:
$$g_{\rho\sigma}+\omega_{\rho\sigma}+\omega_{\sigma\rho}=g_{\rho\sigma}$$

just move terms we can get the correct answer right? But I have no idea about the third term of equation $(*)$:
$$\omega_{\sigma}^{\nu}g_{\mu\nu}\delta_{\rho}^{\mu}$$
I want to know why not in this order:
$$\delta_{\rho}^{\mu}g_{\mu\nu}\omega_{\sigma}^{\nu}$$
then we get this wrong result:
$$g_{\rho\sigma}+\omega_{\rho\sigma}+\omega_{\rho\sigma}=g_{\rho\sigma}$$

Can someone please just told me how to get the correct order?

Comment: You can rearrange the order of the factors in the multiplication. The order doesn't matter. But you seem to have mixed the second and the third term. $\delta^\mu_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}\omega^{\nu}_{\,\,\sigma}=\omega_{\rho\sigma}$ and $\omega^{\mu}_{\,\,\rho}g_{\mu\nu}\delta^\nu_{\sigma}=\omega_{\sigma\rho}$. Also, make sure to use the correct slot for the gammas (first slot of $\omega^a_{\,\,b}$).